# How to change the default selectionColor on fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

how can I change the default bluish selectionColor on fabric.js? I've tried to change these lines in fabric.js but got no effect:

```
selectionColor: 'rgba(17,119,255,0.3)',
selectionBorderColor:   'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
editingBorderColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.25)',
```

Is there any other way?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]
ok, now i see what you need exactly, you want to change the border of the selected grouped object and maybe the squares on the border too.

i tested it on kitchensink, and it works,
you have to catch the selection event , and inside the event you change the **borderColor** and **cornerColor** properties of the **activeGroup**.

**your object:selected event:**

```js
canvas.on('object:selected', function(o) {
    var activeObj = o.target;
    if (activeObj.get('type') == 'group') {
        activeObj.set({
            'borderColor':'#fbb802',
            'cornerColor':'#fbb802'
        });
    }
});
```

hope helps, good luck.

Comment: It works, thanks! Although the cornerColor doesn't get changed, at least the borderColor get changed to something darker. Wish I could set the thickness as well.

Comment: Alas, later I found out it makes the free drawing mode malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the border color (it shows when you select object) of fabric objects with this parameter: **borderColor**

for example :

```
canvas._objects[0].set({'borderColor':'#fbb802'});
canvas.renderAll();
```

hope helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either. I'm using kitchensink. There must be somewhere that defines this soft bluish color. I've tried to search based on the color hex, but can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectionBorderColor` property.

```js
canvas.selectionBorderColor = 'red';
```

For more information visit: http://fabricjs.com/customization

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot I finally found a solution to change the default format style when selecting more than one object.

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.set({     
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerStyle: 'circle',
    cornerColor: '#3880ff',
    cornerSize: 12,
})
```